# constexpr, or not constexpr, that is the question

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

I was playing around with `constexpr` in C++ and noticed a strange behavior that I wish to understand. Consider this code from 5.19 section of Standard.

```
constexpr int f1(int k) {
    constexpr int x = k; // error: x is not initialized by a
                         // constant expression because lifetime of k
                         // began outside the initializer of x
    return x;
}
```

As error states, lifetime of `k` began outside the initializer of `x`, thus we can't be sure that `x` *will be* a constant expression.

And here the another version of the same function.

```
constexpr int f1(int k) {
    return k;
}
```

This one is totally fine and usable. So question is why, here also, the lifetime of `k` began outside of initializer of return value, or not, or this is because of RVO and technically if just follow the Standard this also should be an error?

And also another question, from which this one actually arise. I was trying to write `constexpr` IPv4 class. For that purpose I've used constructor with `std::string_view`. So I was able to have this in compile time using gcc 10.3 and -std=c++20

```
constexpr IPv4 myIP{"192.168.0.0"};
constexpr size_t count = myIP.countOfDots(); // calls std::count which is constexpr in C++20
```

Now I want to validate that IP is correct, so I need to check count of dots to be equal to 3, which I can easily do here by

```
if constexpr (count != 3)
```

The question is how to organize this into some function, which will also allow me to do such a check in compile time for any given IP, basically I want something like this

```
constexpr bool validateIP(const IPv4& ip);
```

And as in the example above, I can't just have this in that function

```
constexpr size_t count = ip.countOfDots();
```

So is it possible to do the way I want?

Comment: "*Now I want to validate that IP is correct, so I need to check count of dots to be equal to 3, which I can easily do here by*" Why are you using `if constexpr` here? Are you trying to discard some statements because they would be inappropriate to instantiate if `count` is not 3? Otherwise, there's no point to doing that and you just meant `if`.

Comment: From your comment and the answer I understood that I really misunderstood what ```constexpr``` function means, now it's clear, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function that's `constexpr` means that the function *potentially* can be evaluated at compile-time. The function must however also be callable with a run-time value, and produce a run-time result.

A variable that's `constexpr` has to be a compile time constant. Period.

What that means for your `validateIP` function is that you don't need to make `count` `constexpr`. You can write a function and mark it as `constexpr`.

When you call the function with a compile time constant, it will get evaluated at compile time.

If you call it with a run time value it will get evaluated at run time.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool validateIP(const std::string_view& ip) {
    int count = 0;
    for (auto& c : ip) {
        if (c == '.') {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count == 3;
}

int main()
{
    // Assigning the value to a constexpr is not needed to make the function
    // be evaluated at compile time, but it proves that it is in this case
    constexpr auto isValid1 = validateIP("123.456.789.0");

    std::cout << isValid1;
}
```

Comment: I understood that I really misunderstood what ```constexpr``` function means, now it's clear, thanks for help :)